ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Devise::Sessions#new Authorization gem Devise
I am trying to authorize on the site using gem devise. when i go to the authorization page i get an error.
I am trying to authorize on the site using gem devise. when i go to the authorization page i get an error.
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Devise::Sessions#new
Showing /home/yura/toyshop-main/app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb where line #10 raised:
No route matches {:action=>"home", :controller=>"devise/articles"}
Extracted source (around line #10):
8
9
10
11
12
13
    <ul class="nav col-12 col-lg-auto me-lg-auto mb-2 justify-content-center mb-md-0">
      
     <%= link_to t('header.menu.home'), home_path, class: "nav-link px-2 text-white #{current_page?(controller: 'articles', action: 'home') ? 'link-secondary' : 'link-dark'}" %>
     <%= link_to t('header.menu.delivery'), delivery_path, class: "nav-link px-2 text-white #{current_page?(controller: 'articles', action: 'delivery') ? 'link-secondary' : 'link-dark'}" %>
     <%= link_to t('header.menu.contacts'), contacts_path, class: "nav-link px-2 text-white #{current_page?(controller: 'articles', action: 'contacts') ? 'link-secondary' : 'link-dark'}" %>
     <%= link_to t('header.menu.answers'), answers_path, class: "nav-link px-2 text-white #{current_page?(controller: 'articles', action: 'answers') ? 'link-secondary' : 'link-dark'}" %>

Trace of template inclusion: #<ActionView::Template app/views/layouts/application.html.erb locals=[]>
Rails.root: /home/yura/toyshop-main
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:10
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:14
Request
Parameters:
None
Toggle session dump
Toggle env dump
Response
Headers:
None
x




My header.html file
    <ul class="nav col-12 col-lg-auto me-lg-auto mb-2 justify-content-center mb-md-0">
      
     <%= link_to t('header.menu.home'), home_path, class: "nav-link px-2 text-white #{current_page?(controller: 'articles', action: 'home') ? 'link-secondary' : 'link-dark'}" %>
     <%= link_to t('header.menu.delivery'), delivery_path, class: "nav-link px-2 text-white #{current_page?(controller: 'articles', action: 'delivery') ? 'link-secondary' : 'link-dark'}" %>
     <%= link_to t('header.menu.contacts'), contacts_path, class: "nav-link px-2 text-white #{current_page?(controller: 'articles', action: 'contacts') ? 'link-secondary' : 'link-dark'}" %>
     <%= link_to t('header.menu.answers'), answers_path, class: "nav-link px-2 text-white #{current_page?(controller: 'articles', action: 'answers') ? 'link-secondary' : 'link-dark'}" %>
      <%= link_to t('header.menu.about'), about_path, class: "nav-link px-2 text-white #{current_page?(controller: 'articles', action: 'about') ? 'link-secondary' : 'link-dark'}" %>
    </ul>

    <form class="col-12 col-lg-auto mb-3 mb-lg-0 me-lg-3" role="search">
      <input type="search" class="form-control form-control-dark text-bg-white" placeholder="Пошук..." aria-label="Search">
    </form>

      <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <div class="text-end">

      <%= button_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, data: { "turbo-method": :delete } %>
      
      <% else %>

      <%= link_to new_user_session_path do %>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light me-2">Увійти</button>
      <% end %>
      <%= link_to new_user_registration_path do %>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Реєстрац</button>
      <% end %>
       <% end %>
       
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

My route.rb file
Rails.application.routes.draw do
   devise_for :users

   root "welcome#index"

   

   get 'home', to: 'articles#home'
   get 'delivery', to: 'articles#delivery'
   get 'contacts', to: 'articles#contacts'
   get 'answers', to: 'articles#answers'
   get 'about', to: 'articles#about'
end


do you have routes for this inside routes.rb?

added routes file

Would you like to execute rails routes and put the outputs here? My verdict is Rails doesn't recognize home_path.

@AgungPrasetyo no - that would have lead to a NoMethodError. The problem cannot actually be reproduced with the code given.
